# Problems installing AppEngine plugin in Eclipse 3.7, on Mountain Lion

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-indigo

I've been trying to install the Appengine plugin for eclipse 3.7 Indigo, and I am getting an error which reads:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
    Software being installed: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37             (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:
Go to "Help" menu
Select "Install new software"
Enter into "Work with:" box: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7
Click "Add"
Select packages, click next. And then it returns that error.

I read through a bunch of solved stackoverflow problems already, but none seem to work for me. If it's any help, I'm on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.
I've installed the Appengine plugin a long time ago without a hitch on my laptop (10.6 Snow Leopard). Is there something that I am doing wrong or a known bug that is preventing me from installing this Eclipse plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed. Ran it in windows, frieking worked.